# Javascript: Event-Handling / Content-Update / Submit

Tags: javascript, event-handling, form-submit

**This is my simple HTML-form (shorted):**

```
<form name="formular" action="./import.php" method="post" onsubmit="buttonClicked();">
    <input name="notes" onchange="notesChanged();" />
    <input name="info" onchange="infoChanged();" />
    <input name="doit" class="button" type="submit" value="validate" />
</form>
```

When the two fields are changed, the button-label might change to 'submit', 'submit-different' or back to 'validate'.
When editing **and leaving** a field via 'tab', this works great: The user is shown the special way, the form is submitted.

**My problem:**

When a field is changed and **not** left via 'tab' but directly by clicking the button, than the label might also be changed and in this case, the form should not be submitted.

I have no idea, how to handle this case, because all field-events are process even before any button-event.

Comment: In newer browsers you could use the `input` event rather than the `change` event, since that doesn't require the element to lose focus before it's fired. That really depends on what `notesChanged` and `infoChanged` do, though.

Comment: The one was new to me and did it. If you post as an answer, I will check as accepted. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer browsers you can use the `input` event. This functions similarly to the `change` event but doesn't require the element to lose focus (due to the <kbd>tab</kbd> key being pressed or the user clicking elsewhere on the page) before it fires. The [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) has information on browser support.

That would ensure that the text of your button is updated as the user makes changes to the other two inputs, and as a result before they click on the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a blur event using jquery. It fires when the input field looses focus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $('#notes').blur(function () {
       notesChanged();
     });

     $('#info').blur(function () {
       infoChanged();
     });
   });
</script>


<form name="formular" action="./import.php" method="post" onsubmit="buttonClicked();">
   <input id="notes"/>
   <input id="info"/>
   <input name="doit" class="button" type="submit" value="validate" />
</form>
```

Comment: onblur is also processed before onclick/onsubmit (like onchange)